# How to flatten a list containing lists with different numbers of dictionaries?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a python code like below:

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def func(first, sec):
    results = []
    for x in range(first):
        result_dict = {"a": x, "b": x**sec, "c": x/sec}
        results.append(result_dict.copy())
    return results

with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    res = pool.starmap(func, [(a, 8) for a in range(1, 4)])
```

Then I flatten the `res` with this piece of code:

```py
res = np.asarray(res)
res = res.reshape(-1)
res = np.array(res).tolist()
```

After that when I print the `res` the output is like below:

```
[[{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0}],
 [{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0.125}],
 [{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0},
  {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0.125},
  {'a': 2, 'b': 256, 'c': 0.25}]]
```

But I want the output to be like this:

```
[{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0},
 {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0.125},
 {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0.125},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 256, 'c': 0.25}]
```

Do you have any idea how to change the code to get the desired result for `res` ?

Comment: ``from itertools import chain; list(chain(*t))``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`chain.from_iterable` of `itertools` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) lets you chain sub-lists to one list.

```
import itertools

res = [[{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0}],
 [{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0.125}],
 [{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0},
  {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0.125},
  {'a': 2, 'b': 256, 'c': 0.25}]]


print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(res)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As in your example you have dictionaries stored in a list of lists, a list comprehension also works:

```
res = [[{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0}],
 [{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0.125}],
 [{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0},
  {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0.125},
  {'a': 2, 'b': 256, 'c': 0.25}]]

flat_res = [item for items in res for item in items]
```

#### Output

```
print(flat_res)
# [{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0}, {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0.125}, {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0.0}, {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 0.125}, {'a': 2, 'b': 256, 'c': 0.25}]
```